# display related records from my database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to display record related to a specific primary key based on the foreign keys in other tables. How to  display records for that primary key in other tables using php??

for example:

```
table1

primary key 1: plate#1
primary key 2: plate#2
primary key 3: plate#3

table2

primary key 1: destination|route|revenue|plate# 1
primary key 2: destination|route|revenue|plate# 3

table3

primary key 1: diesel price|number of liters|plate# 1

primary key 2: diesel price|number of liters|plate# 3
```

I already created a page that will display all the data in `table1`. I want to display the data in `table1` and `table2` that are related to the data in `table1` when I made the database they already had relationship with each other. My problem is just displaying the record related to `table1`.  I want to display records for just `plate#1`, another for `plate#2` and so on.

Comment: what is your desired result then?

Comment: Can u show the example result?

Comment: See my answer to this post. [Exploring data modelling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170774/exploring-data-modelling-how-to-hobble-a-sensible-database-together/6170801#6170801)

Comment: my desired result is when clicking the plate number in the table it will go to a page called delivery and truckdelivery the delivery and fuel records related to the plate number <td><a href="truckdelivery.php?id_truck=<?php echo $row_truck['id_truck']?>"><?php echo $row_truck['truck_plate_no']; ?></a></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a crude example:

```
<?php
  $truck_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['truck_id']);



 $sql_PK = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '{$truck_id}'";
 $res_PK = mysql_query($sql_PK);
 $row_PK = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_PK);

 $truck_plate = $row_PK['plate'];



$truck_plate = mysql_real_escape_string($truck_plate);



$sql = "SELECT table2.plate, table2.destination, table2.route, table3.plate, table3.diesel_price, table3.num_of_liters FROM table2, table3 WHERE table2.plate = table3.plate AND table2.plate = '{$truck_plate}'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);


    // this will give you the details from the following

        //TABLE2
        // plate
        // destination
        // route

        //TABLE3
        // plate
        // diesel_price
        // num_of_liters


?>
```

There's a couple of important things to remember. First is get in the habit of naming your fields without spaces in the database and use _ instead. so diesel price is diesel_price, etc. Secondly is to make sure that you are protecting yourself from any injections like I have shown here using the mysql_real_escape_string

So when someone clicks on truckdetails.php?plate=mrtchi it's going to query the database based on the plate number: mrtchi

Comment: ahhhhhh so how does this get[id] work?? what do i do to activate it to get the plate i want?

Comment: on the say showtrucks.php page you need to loop over all possible plates from a table in the database. One you do the query do this: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$plate = $row['plate'];

echo '<a href="truckdetails.php?plate=' . $plate . '">' . $plate . '</a>';
}

Comment: mrtechie can primary keys also work like truckdelivery.php?id_truck=<?php echo $row_truck['id_truck']?>

Comment: @JustinCapunoCuizon you can use whatever you want, but you just need to make sure that along the trail things match up. So if you start off with a primary key, you need to either make sure that primary key from table1 is in table2 and table3 as a reference. Or you need to extract the plate# and then go from there.

Comment: yes tnx i have already foreign key for my primary keys for the other tables so i will just join the other primary key and the foreign key and use it for the query tnx mtechie

Comment: i tried modifying the code above it displays just the first record in the table that i included mrtechie

Comment: not the record that is for the specific plate everytime i click a plate no it displays the same record the first record in the table

Comment: and mrtechie i dont know what to echo out to see the records i just echo out $row_PK['delivery_details_destination'] and it displays the first record not every plate but the first record for all

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to join tables to get the final results. Join allows you to essentially merge tables together and get a single result based on the selections. Google php mysql join table and look at some of the examples. Here's one for you: [Join Tables](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)

Comment: i joined the table already but when i display it it shows all the joined data i just want the data that is for the specific plate number

Comment: Make sure in your WHERE clause it's specifying just that plate number you wanted.

Comment: @JustinCapunoCuizon - would you like an example?

Comment: ahhhh so just the plate number i wanted tnx2 for the info

Comment: how about i made a table for the plate and if i add a plate number it increments the table automatically i made the plate number inside the table into a link that will take them to another page called truckdelivery.php this is the code for the link href="truckdelivery.php?id_truck=<?php echo $row_truck['id_truck']?> i wanted to make a different result everytime i click another plate number

Comment: if you have a page called truckdelivery.php and at the top of that page has say $truck_id = $_GET['id']; Then you can query the database to get just the data for that id/plate, and have it render on the page.

Comment: i dont know the get[id] part can u give me an example please mrtechie?

Comment: mrtechie this is the code i made based in your suggestions xD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002831/i-dont-know-what-error-i-have